# Sculpting artifacts when using anchored alpha

Tags: transparency, sculpting

I get these strange artifacts when using a textured alpha brush in Anchored stroke mode. It's a persistent rippling action when the brush is dragged out past a certain size. It doesn't happen when I uncheck Front Faces Only, but I don't want to do that because the spherical falloff enables the stroke to carry through the mesh to the other side. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm sculpting on a Multires modifier with 4 subdivs.

[image]